# ClassNotPreparedException Exception while running a uniTest with PowerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I have a unit Test class with one method that tries to mock a class with static methods.
When I try to mock the class I get the following exception: class not prepared for test.
The unit Test is located in an automation infrastructure that uses TestNG AND Maven in Java.
I don't know if something is conflicted with my dependencies or the class itself, or something else is missing.
Here is the PowerMockito dependencies in my POM file:

```
<properties>
    <powermock.version>2.0.2</powermock.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-testng</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here is the example of my unit Test class and test method with the problem:

```
    public class myUnitTest {

    @PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
    @Test
    public static void test1() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyClass.class);
        List <String> userList = (List<String>) Mockito.when(MyClass.variableMap.get("Users")).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"user1"})); 
    }
  }
```